# How to pass InputStream value in Struts 2 action class to Ajax in JSP page and convert the value into JSON Array

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, struts2

I want to pass JSON array from Struts 2 action class to JSP page. I'm trying to send the data set as a string. The thing I want to know is, How can I read those data in JavaScript.

**This is my method in `Action` class:**

```java
private InputStream inputStream;

/* getter and setter*/

public String getClientMilestone() throws DAOTransientException, DBConfigException{
        PaymentScheduleDao paymentScheduleDao = new PaymentScheduleDao();
        List <PaymentMilestone> paymentScheduleInfo = paymentScheduleDao.getClientMilestoneInfo(projectId);
        String result = "[";

        for(int i=0; i<paymentScheduleInfo.size(); i++){
            
            result += "{"+"'"+"item"+i+"' : {"+ "'"+"milestoneName"+ "'"+":"+"'"+paymentScheduleInfo.get(i).getMilestone_name()+"'"+"}"+"},";
            
        }
        result += "]";
        System.out.println("result is "+result);
        inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(result);
        return "success";
    }
```

**It prints as below:**

```js
result is [{'item0' : {'milestoneName':'milestone 1'}},{'item1' : {'milestoneName':'milestone 2'}}]
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<package name="ClientMilestone" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getClientMilestone" class="packageName.PaymentScheduleAction" method="getClientMilestone">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
            <result name="failure">./LandingPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">./Error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

**JavaScript function in JSP:**

```js
function createOrViewPs() {
    
    var projectId = document.getElementById("projectId").value;
    $.ajax({ 
        method: "GET",
        url: "getClientMilestone",
        data: {"projectId" : projectId},
        traditional: true, 
        success:
            function(result){
                var jsonArr = result;
            
                for (var i=0; i<jsonArr.length; i++)
                    for (var name in jsonArr[i]) {
                        alert("Item name: "+name);
                        alert("Source: "+jsonArr[i][name].milestoneName);
                }
            },
        error: 
            function(){
                alert("fail");
            }
    });         
}
```

Comment: Use Struts json plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you return a stringified version of JSON from the server with the `stream` result type (Note, that stream result type might not be appropriate, see below), you need to parse it to JSON with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and if you are using jQuery better use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var jsonArr = JSON.parse(result);
$.each (jsonArr, function(index, value){
  $.each (value, function(key, value){
    console.log("Item name: "+key);
    console.log("Source: "+value.milestoneName);
  });
});
```

---

What you did wrong is building json manually. You should use a tool that serializes Java object to JSON. Struts2 has [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) available jar in the package that can be used to serialize to json, or if you are using [`struts2-json-plugin`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html) then it has built-in serializer. if you are using [`struts2-rest-plugin`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/rest-plugin.html) then you can use other serializer like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). The way you choose the library to serialize your data is out of the scope of this answer. You can find many examples on SO and on [Struts site](http://struts.apache.org/). Most of them using json plugin that returns JSON object that supports by the browser, i.e. doesn't need parsing, however parsing for JSON is useful to avoid errors and data lose.

Comment: I am using struts2-json-plugin. As you have told I create json object and then put those object into json array.Then I send those array to jQuery as above. But in console "Item name" is ok. Source is "undefined".

Comment: I didn't see it in the question. Also I didn't tell you *create json object and then put those object into json array*. I said **You should use a tool that serializes Java object to JSON.**

Comment: problem solved. Thank you. By the way, Is there a way to pass date via json array

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35706457/573032) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27686588/573032). Better if you ask a full fledged question.